# Magento: Cant find template

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I see a call

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
```

in cart.phtml. I cannot find this file anywhere. I am new to Magento, Could you tell me a location where this file should ideally reside? Also, do these templates also load from Database and should I check there/

Kind regards
Khuram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find this you need to do a little bit of tracing :).

We need to look in a "layout.xml" file since this is where "ChildHtml" blocks are declared. Since this is the Cart,which is part of the *Checkout* module, we need to look in `checkout.xml`.

You should find the line declaring the "coupon" block under the `checkout_cart_index` section of this file. Here it is:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
```

So, `checkout/cart/coupon.phtml` is the template file you are looking for. You can see 
it is assigned the name "coupon" with the `as="coupon"` line.

This file will probably be in the folder `/app/design/frontend/default/default/checkout/cart/coupon.phtml` and you should copy it your custom theme directory, which will automatically override the default and use your new coupon.phtml template file.

I hope this helps, and happy Magentoing

Comment: This helps alot. Infact I found the file. However, The languages are all in this->__ format. Where do I insert my own headings for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... yes most Magneto text is wrapped in the __() translation method for easy internationalization, this is normal and a good convention to keep. What do you mean by "Headings"?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I just changed the text in there. Its working great now. The site was in a new template but the coupon file was in the base template. Didnt figure that out. Thanks indeed.